# No.of faces in Peterson graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

I know that Peterson graph is not planar.But in this graph how can I determine the regions of the faces.How many faces does it include?  Two faces can't include a common region right?

Comment: Faces are really only defined for planar graphs. Of course, you could get into topological embeddings of graphs and define a more abstract concept of a face. This would largely rely on the surface and its genus, though. This thread may be of some value as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206414/faces-of-a-non-planar-graph

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "face" is not really defined for non-planar graphs. One can count the faces in the simplest embeddings of the graph into some surface. The Petersen graph can be embedded in the real projective plane with 6 faces (as the quotient of a dodecahedron by the antipodal map), or on the torus with 5 faces.