# How to count the faces of a graph using a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, graph-theory

### Background

I recently decided to try to create (my own) algebraic formulation (Disclaimer! Not sure if it already exists) for graph theory. Consider the following graph:

[image: A polygon with vertices B and D connected]

A is connected with B and C

B is connected with A,E and D

E is connected with B and D

D is connected with E,B and C

C is connected with A and D

Writing this algebraically with a $f_A = $ the sum of the vertices connected $A$ the vertex = $ B + C$

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    f_A\\
    f_B\\
    f_C\\
    f_D\\
    f_E
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}}_{M}
.
\begin{pmatrix}
    A\\
    B\\
    C\\
    D\\
    E
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

We obtain a symmetric Matrix $M$ (which I believe encodes all the information about the graph). The number of vertices are simply the dimension of $M$ which is is $\dim M$. The number of edges is given by $ (1 1 1 1 1) . M . (1 1 1 1 1)^T/2$.

### Question

The next question was how do I **count the number of faces?** (directly from the matrix)

This is where I got stuck. I could use the Euler characteristic formula if I was assuming the graph was 2-D but within the formulation of the $M$ matrix one can imagine an n dimensional graph. For higher dimensional graphs one is allowed to assume only holes are formed.

Comment: What are the "faces" if your graph doesn't fit into the plane without crossings?  For example, what are the "faces" of $K_5$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $K_5$ would be realizable in some higher dimension graph which assuming to have holes would have some number of faces. To construct a similar graph as $K-5$ one would have to label the intersection as a vertex.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks and corrected ...

Comment: My point is, if you can't decide how many faces $K_5$ has without further assumptions, then there is definitely no way to get a reasonable answer from the matrix of the graph.  I can't think of any algebra you can perform on a matrix to produce the answer "it has some number of faces, *if you realize it as a higher dimensional graph*".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix (Your construction is not original but is very useful! For example, one can profitably think of it as an linear operator on the space of complex valued functions on the vertices of the graph, and this is where spectral graph theory comes from.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Are you saying that the condition that: "For higher dimensional graphs one is allowed to assume only holes are formed." is not sufficient?

Comment: I'm saying that matrix algebra produces numbers, not statements.  I have no idea what that sentence means to you, but I know that it's not a number.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206414/faces-of-a-non-planar-graph) for a discussion of what "faces" might mean in a non-planar graph