# How to count the number of faces or regions of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to count the number of faces or regions of a graph such as the below graph:
[image]

The graph has 12 vertices and 17 edges. But I am unable to find the number of faces of the graph. I don't know how to find the faces. Help me to find the number of faces.

Comment: Faces are not usually defined unless you have a planar embedding  (a picture of the graph without crossings). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206480/26369) for more.

Comment: @MarkS.I think you should mark this question as a duplicate of the one you've linked to.

Comment: The given graph is not a planar graph hence there is no reasonable definition for its "faces".

Comment: How many faces are there in the given graph?

Comment: @Jack I think you should post that (ideally with an argument) as an answer since "use Euler's formula" is not correct.

Comment: @MarkS.: suggestion accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use Euler's formula
$$V-E+F=2$$
Where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges, and $F$ is the number of faces.

Comment: Sir I asked what is the number of faces in the given graph and small suggestion on how to find the number of faces.

Comment: Don't faces only exist in planar graphs?

Comment: That works if the graph is given with a planar embedding, but is "not even wrong" otherwise as the faces are not defined. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206480/26369) for more.

Comment: Sir I am in Graph theory and I am having problem to find out the number of faces of the given graph above. Would you help me at that point ?

Comment: Yes. To find the number of faces plug in the number of vertices and the number of edges into the above formula, and then solve for $F$, the number of faces.

Comment: @frpzzd, your answer is not correct if the graph is not planar.

Answer (score 6):

The depicted graph has a $K_{3,3}$ (complete bipartite graph on six vertices) as a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor). By [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) such graph **is not** a planar graph, hence it makes no sense to talk about its *faces*, unless you [embed such graph in a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph) or in a surface with [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) $\geq 1$:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Euler's theorem $f+n-m=2$.
$n$: number of vertices.
$m$: number of edges.
$f$: number of faces.