# Is there a notion of "face" for bounded genus graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Is there a notion of "face" for bounded genus graphs?

For instance given fixed genus $k$ is there some $q$ for which  there are $q$ sets of cycles  $S_1, S_2,.., S_q$ each $G[S_i]$ is planar $S_i$ is a subset of faces of $G[S_i]$   each cycle of $G$ can be written as the symmetric difference of cycles in $\cup_{i=1}^q S_i $?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand fully the question, but there sure is a notion of face for any genus graph, as Euler's formulas can be generalised as
$$ V-E+F=2-2g$$
Where $g$ is the genus of the graph's embedding.

You might want ot have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206414/faces-of-a-non-planar-graph)

Comment: $G[S_i] $ refers to  the subgraph consisting of all edges and verticies that are in some cycle in $S_i$ hence while G is non planar $G[S_i]$ may be. 
a further question could be is there a map  from  a surface with k handles to the plane such that each G[S_i] contains no crossings under such a map (simple case would be consider a bounded genus surface to have k "bridges" and the map to be just let everything on the bridge "fall" so that edges that used to go over the bridge now are in the plane and cross other edges